# Can't enable spring orm/transaction logging even when log4j.xml is configured

Tags: spring-mvc, logging, orm, log4j, eclipselink

I have a configuration problem regarding enabling spring related logging in my application as I'm using EclipseLink,JPA 2.0 & Spring 4.0, I need to verify when the entity manager is closed or cleaned up while doing transactions.

My application is JTA enabled so everything is controlled by my container (Websphere).Here is my log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!-- CONSOLE normally used in desktop environment -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%-8X{context}] %-5p %-40.40c{2} - %m%n"/>
        </layout> 
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE_APPENDER" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="C:\\proj\\was\\logs\\spring.log"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'-'yyyy-MM-dd'.txt'"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-4p [%t] %C{2} - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <!-- Spring -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.transaction" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.orm.jpa" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER"/>
    </logger>



     <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER" />
    </root> 

</log4j:configuration>
```

I have also tried many solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756707/cannot-enable-spring-debug-logging-using-log4j), but it didn't help.Please help me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What is your issue exactly ? You did not have any log ? you have missing log ?  Be ware, spring use slf4j so you need the slf4j-log4j12 jar to be able to log stuff on log4j

Comment: @wargre I need to enable spring internal logger.debug() logs to my console or to a file I have configured log4j.xml and have necessary jars but still it wont print logs. I will try your suggestion of slf4j-log4j12 jar but which version of the jar should I download ?

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, it seems that you not have the adapter slf4j to log4j. Or have another adapter.

To check the adapter in use, use the code:

```
StaticLoggerBinder binder = StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton();
System.out.println(binder.getLoggerFactoryClassStr());
```

If it is not the log4j12 adapter showing:

- Check on the war, you should have a slf4j-api-xxxx.jar in WEB-INF/lib.
- put the slf4j-log4j12-xxxx.jar  (same version) into WEB-INF/lib
- if there is logback-xxxxx.jar remove it, else slf4j will take it to log
- if there is log4j-over-slf4j-xxxx.jar  remove it, else it is possible that log4j log will be redirected to slf4j that will redirect to log4j and so on..
- there is perhaps another adapter (slf4j-jcl-xxxx.jar for instance) that need to be removed.

Comment: I have following jars in my lib folder for logging log4j-1.2.9.jar
slf4j.api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j.jdk14-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar commons-logging.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar ----------Still cant able to print logs, where I'm goign wrong

Comment: remove slf4j.jdk14-1.6.1.jar and  slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar.   put slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar (slf4j need to be same version).

Comment: Can you put this code  StaticLoggerBinder binder = StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton(); System.out.println(binder.getLoggerFactoryClassStr());   (or put the String somewhere you know you can read) in  your application so that we can be sure what the logger used by slf4j ?

Comment: I tried that code this is what it prints "org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory"

Comment: It means the slf4j.jdk14-1.6.1.jar jar is still there. one way or the other. so JDK logging is used instead of log4j.

Comment: Now I completely removed slf4j.jdk14-1.6.1.jar dependancy and it prints "org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory"

Comment: If your log4j.xml file is in the WEB-INF/classes directory it should be ok. Except if you have a specific location describe in your web.xml

Comment: its in my \MyApp-EAR\resources\properties\desktop\log4j.xml which is defined as my classpath value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151737/discussion-between-wargre-and-angular-10).

Answer (score 0):

#### Logger Hierarchy

In most logging systems, logger has the parent and child relationship, in which children inherit

- Level
- Appender
- ResourceBoudle

from father logger. And the root logger exists at the top of inheritance. The children will send log event to father logger depending on `additivity`. False means it will not send log to father logger.

So, from your original config, you didn't allow Spring related logger to send log to your root logger.

#### Suggestions

So, now we understand that we should set `additivity` to true and change the log4j config into like following:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.transaction" additivity="true"/>

<logger name="org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils" additivity="true"/>

<logger name="org.springframework.orm.jpa" additivity="true"/>

 <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER" />
</root>
```

#### More

- [Here](http://tonyz93.blogspot.com/2017/08/slf4j-introduction.html) and [here](http://tonyz93.blogspot.com/2017/08/slf4j-introduction2-output.html) are the blog posts I write about slf4j & log4j & logback, which Spring uses, and you can read to enhance the understanding of logging;
- If you change the `additivity` and still can't see the log in console/file, I suggest you set a breakpoint at any logging line in `EntityManagerFactoryUtils`, then step in code to see what's wrong;

---

#### Update

The logger of `EntityManagerFactoryUtils`, as we can from source code, is not slf4j or log4j. It is commons logging. So your log4j config about this class will not work.

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;

private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.class);
```

In order to make your config work, you should make some [bridge work](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html):

- exclude `commons-logging.jar` from spring-orm
- add `jcl-over-slf4j.jar`
- make sure you have `slf4j-api & slf4j-log4j`

Comment: It goes into Jdk14Logger 1.2 version method public void debug(Object message) {       log(Level.FINE, String.valueOf(message), null);
   } still couldn't print logs

Comment: I'm not using maven and its a legacy app build with ant so how to achieve the first step ? exclude commons-logging.jar from spring-orm

Comment: Well, I didn't use ant, so you try [this link](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/ivyfile/artifact-exclude.html) and [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205592/exclude-jar-from-ant-classpath)

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the Jars on your classpath some cleaning is probably required, but in order to do so we need to understand what each of the Jars do.

**log4j-1.2.9.jar**
Is the implementation of Log4j. This one is required in order to log anything using Log4j and of course reading your log4j configuration file.

**slf4j.api-1.6.1.jar**
Is the Slf4j API library, Only required if you or some of your third-party dependencies use Slf4j for logging, which seem quite likely as you already have it on your classpath. This allows you to write to the logs through Slf4J API, e.g:

```
private static final Logger LOG = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyLoggingClass.class);
```

**slf4j.jdk14-1.6.1.jar**
Is a JDK 1.4, also known as java.util.logging binding for Slf4j used to use java.util.logging as the logging engine when Slf4j is used. Obviously we're going to use log4j as the logging implementation and not java.util.logging meaning this should be removed.

**slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar**
Is a log4j 1.2 binding for Slf4j, required to route logs from Slf4j to your Log4j implementation. This one is only required if *slf4j.api-1.6.1.jar* was required. However, versions should be harmonized in order to avoid conflicts.

**commons-logging-1.1.1.jar** and
**commons-logging.jar**
As far as I can tell those are both the commons logging framework. This is the logging framework used by Spring. However, you should only have one of those on your classpath, where I recommend using the one which reveals it's version.

Having the correct Jars on your classpath, commons logging *should* be able to pick up the correct logging implementation for you (which in your case is Log4j). If that's not the case, explicitly put a file named *commons-logging.properties* on the root of your classpath and add the following line to it:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4jLogger
```

forcing it to use Log4j as the logging implementation.

Comment: org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4jLogger add this throws me class not found exception even jars are present in my lib

Comment: Which version of WebSphere are you running on? Can you please verify that you're using a commons-logging version new enough to support Log4j 1.2, such as the 1.1.1 version? Which commons-logging being used may be verified by enabling class loader logging, using JVM option -verbose:class

Comment: IBM Websphere 8.5.5.8 yes I have 1.1.1 version